# Using my server to do computationally heavy tasks

Tags: linux, file-sharing, remote, chroot

I have a laptop I do most of my computing on but it's very lightweight and it takes ages to compile anything on, or do any heavy tasks. Something like installing an emacs plugin or a cabal package can take a pretty long while. I also own a rather beefy home server(it can run circles around my laptop computation-wise) that doesn't do much and I'd like to use it more.

As I'm not a Linux guru, I'm not sure where to start with this. I've considered using something like sshfs to mount my laptop on my server and chroot to my laptop, but it seems difficult and I thought there might be a way to automate this already.

Is there a good way to simply 'pipe'(for a lack of a better word) commands to my server using my local filesystem? I have Debian Linux on both computers.

Comment: You mean aside from running a terminal on your laptop to control the processes on the server?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't very clear -- I meant compile(etc) things /for/ my laptop while leveraging my server's power, I don't leave my server on most of the time due to not being home and electricity costs ;)

Comment: If the laptop and server are connected via network, it doesn't matter where the files are. For compiling a executable, the process can be tailored for the computer it is to be executed on. In short, you can configure the 2 computers to suit your desires.

Comment: What is the architecture of the CPUs of the 2 systems? That might be something to consider

Answer (score 1):

Use [`distcc`](https://code.google.com/p/distcc/):

> distcc is a program to distribute builds of C, C++, Objective C or Objective C++ code across several machines on a network. distcc should always generate the same results as a local build, is simple to install and use, and is usually much faster than a local compile.
>
> distcc does not require all machines to share a filesystem, have synchronized clocks, or to have the same libraries or header files installed. They can even have different processors or operating systems, if cross-compilers are installed.